# Backbone - make parent model accessible in child views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is there a straight-forward way to make the top level parent model available to the **backbone** child views injected in it?
I have multiple level nested views and would like to be able to access the top level model in the lowest level child view.

Besides **passing the model from parent to child** to nephew and so on, is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: I believe "passing the model from parent to child" is the expected way to do it. Remember that you're simply creating a reference to the parent model when you do this, not a copy.